# Find the length of the line that connects Cylinder's bases

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

> Points $A$ and $B$ are on different bases of the Cylinder. Line $AB$ is on plane $\alpha$, which is parallel to Cylinder's axis. Find the length of line $AB$, if it creates $45^\circ$ angle with the base of the cylinder. Also, cylinder's base has radius $=5$, the distance from the Cylinder's axis to the plane $\alpha$ is $4$.

I translated this problem, so if anything's ambiguous please do comment.

The picture wasn't given, but here's my best attempt (interpretation):

[image]

The dotted line is supposed to be a plane... The perpendicular line is the distance from the the axis to the plane $\alpha$, since it's parallel to the axis, the perpendicular will just lie on the base of the cylinder.. Correct me if i'm wrong here.

So after that, I couldn't really go anywhere, As far as i'm concerned, A and B could be anywhere on the bases... Please try to provide a geometrical view / explanation.

Comment: you are correct. As per the question, the points A and B can be anywhere on the opposite bases as long as they are also on plane $\alpha$. It is clear that the length of the chord made by plane $\alpha$ on the base is 6. Now, you can solve for the answer in form of the height of the cylinder (h) given angle is $45^0$.  It is $h \sqrt2$. When the height of the cylinder is 6,  points A and B are at the circumference and AB becomes $6\sqrt2$. Please note that if the height of the cylinder is more than 6,  this will not even be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I understood the plane parallel to cylinder axis cuts the cylinder at 4 distance units away, making a rectangular shaped intersection area width 6 units in the base plane. Line $AB$ makes minimum $45^{\circ}$ angle to its projection ( or width of rectangle, but not radius!) in this plane of intersection.

[image]

So $AB= 6 \sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Your answer is correct. I have a few questions if I may: First of all, the question never specified that A and B were on the circumference, yet your way of doing and the answer given specifically choose the points to be on the circumference. Why are we allowed to do this? Is the length the same regardless?

Comment: Also, I understand how you got the 3, but why is the length of the side double that? It means that the triangle is isosceles, but I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: I understood that $ A,B $ are on the circular base circumferences what may be called as top and bottom  bases. Next the intersection plane is *parallel* to  to the axis at a constant distance $\sqrt{5^2-4^2},$ so there is symmetry. If they are not disposed this way then the plane parallelism is lost. Width $6$ is double of side length $3$ by symmetry. Important thing to know is that the angle between a line and a plane is the angle between the line and its projection on the plane..and here that line is along the width of section. Hope it is clear enough. Btw, original question which language?

Comment: Oh, okay, I understood the part about the width. The translation is from Georgian and the question did not specify that $A$ and $B$ were on the circumferences, however, the answer said "If A and B are on circumference, then $AB = 6\sqrt2$". I guess, in other cases, you wouldn't be able to find the solution.

Comment: I have on question regarding the angle. "line $AB$ creates $45^\circ$ angle with the base of the cylinder", wouldn't that mean that it creates such angle with the height of the cylinder? As you can see on my drawn picture.

Comment: Yes. We are talking about a cylinder diameter $10$ and height $6$ cut offset $4$ creating a cut square cross-section $ 6 \times 6 $

Comment: I guess it could be the translation.. $A$ and $B$ are on (respective ) *circumferences*..